# C++ Index ordering issue with Boost MultiIndex as an LRU cache

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, lru, boost-multi-index

I have the following LRU implementation made using Boost.MultiIndex bashed on this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/example/serialization.cpp).

The problem is when I change the ordering of the index_by section (and update the enum index_idx accordingly) I get an error on the line that contains:

```
cache_.insert(ci);
```

With the following diagnostic:

> Error 1  error C2661:
>   'boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index::insert'
>   : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments c:\code\code.cpp 79

The code is as follows:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/tag.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

template <typename Key, typename T>
class lru_cache
{
private:

   struct item_t
   {
      Key key;
      T   t;
   };

   typedef boost::multi_index_container
   <
      item_t,
      boost::multi_index::indexed_by
      <
         hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::member<item_t,Key,&item_t::key> >,
         sequenced<>
      >
   > cache_t;

   enum index_idx
   {
      e_map = 0,
      e_seq = 1,
   };

   cache_t cache_;
   size_t max_cache_size_;

public:

   typedef typename std::pair<Key,T> item_pair_t;

   lru_cache(size_t max_cache_size = 1)
   : max_cache_size_(max_cache_size)
   {}

   bool find(const Key& key, T& t)
   {
      typename cache_t::nth_index<e_map>::type& hash_index = cache_.get<e_map>();
      auto itr = hash_index.find(key);
      if (itr != hash_index.end())
      {
         return false;
      }
      t = itr->t;
      typename cache_t::nth_index<e_seq>::type& sequenced_index = cache_.get<e_seq>();
      auto itr2 = cache_.project<e_seq>(itr);
      sequenced_index.relocate(itr2,sequenced_index.end());
      return true;
   }

   void insert(const Key& key, const T& t)
   {
      if (cache_.size() >= max_cache_size_)
      {
         typename cache_t::nth_index<e_seq>::type& sequenced_index = cache_.get<e_seq>();
         sequenced_index.erase(sequenced_index.begin());
      }
      typename cache_t::nth_index<e_map>::type& hash_index = cache_.get<e_map>();
      auto itr = hash_index.find(key);
      item_t ci = {key,t};
      if (itr == hash_index.end())
         cache_.insert(ci);  // <--- Error here....
      else
         hash_index.replace(itr,ci);
   }
};

int main()
{
   typedef lru_cache<int,int> lru_cache_t;
   lru_cache_t lc(2);
   lc.insert(1,1);
   int v;
   lc.find(1,v);
   return 0;
}
```

Modified index ordering:

```
   typedef boost::multi_index_container
   <
      item_t,
      boost::multi_index::indexed_by
      <
         sequenced<>,
         hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::member<item_t,Key,&item_t::key> >
      >
   > cache_t;

   enum index_idx
   {
      e_map = 1,
      e_seq = 0,
   };
```

Comment: Perhaps the last index defined determines the container level methods for things like insert, find etc?

Comment: @iwr1132 the first one.

Answer (score 2):

This is because there's no such an overload of this member function!
Please use [MultiIndex reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/seq_indices.html#modifiers).
You probably mean `cache_.insert(cache_.end(), ci);`